# Trying to rescale a raster with color table but resampling goes wrong

Tags: qgis, raster, gdalwarp

I'm trying to rescale a palletized raster using QGIS (2.14.21), and GDAL (2.2.3), using a bilinear resampling filter, but the resulting colors in the new raster are weird...

Here is the command line:

```
gdalwarp -r bilinear -tr 0.00006 0.00004 -dstnodata 0 -of GTiff C:/source.tif C:/out.tif
```

The source raster (source.tif):
[image]

The resulting raster (out.tif):
[image]

Any idea what could cause this?

Nota:

- I don't have this problem with the "near" filter. But it is the only filter working properly in this case.
- The magenta line in the bottom is the no-data value.

Comment: I assume gdal interpolates as well the colours of the pixels. Maybe you should try to take the most frequent value from values used to calculate the value instead of the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other interpolation methods than "nearest" give weird results for pseudocolor image. For example the average of palette colors 4 and 6 is palette color 5 but what color it really is depends on the palette.

Expand your image from palette into RGB before using gdalwarp. You can do that with gdal_translate by using the -expand option

> **-expand** gray|rgb|rgba: (From GDAL 1.6.0) To expose a dataset with 1 band with a color table as a dataset with 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) bands.
>   Useful for output drivers such as JPEG, JPEG2000, MrSID, ECW that
>   don't support color indexed datasets. The 'gray' value (from GDAL
>   1.7.0) enables to expand a dataset with a color table that only contains gray levels to a gray indexed dataset.

As a side effect of expanding is that the size of the image will get much larger. Compressing the image helps a bit (creation option -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE) but you can also turn the result back to palette image with the rgb2pct utility http://www.gdal.org/rgb2pct.html. Compression is useful even then but I am not sure if you give creation options directly for rgb2pct or if you must make a second run with gdal_translate.